# Is there some way not to repeat the code in inherited classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an abstract class **A** and 2 classes that inherits from class A wchich are **B** and **C**. Let's leave class B and take a closer look to class **C**. I have couple of classes that inherits from class **C** wchich are **C1**, **C2** and so on...

```
class A{
protected:
char symbol;
public:
virtual char get_symbol() = 0;
};

class C : public A{
public:
virtual char get_symbol() { return symbol;}
};

class C1 : public C{
protected:
char symbol = '#';
};
```

The problem is that when i want to call a get_symbol() method for **C1**,**C2**... objects i am getting a method from **C** and some random chars. I have to write:

```
char get_symbol() { return symbol;}
```

for all of the Cn classes to get their actual symbol.

My question is: is there any solution to avoid code redundance and get the proper symbol of Cn objects(the **C** type object doesn't even have his symbol)

Regards

Comment: You are 'overloading' the meaning of `symbol`. You have one idea in class C, but apparently a different idea in class C1. (PS how can you have `char symbol = 'C1'` - does that even compile?)

Comment: You are right, i just gave a stupid symbol value example.

Comment: Not using real code is always a trap - you may get people voting to close as a typo etc because your code is not valid. Always better to give a real snippet.

Comment: Remove the unused `symbol` variable from `A` it will only cause problems.

Comment: Also note that the "random chars" you have been getting are because you didn't set `A::symbol` to any value, so it is picking up whatever value is already in its stack memory.

Comment: Why do you put `get_symbol` as pure virtual in `class A` and `class A` has a member named `symbol`?

Comment: And, always initialize member with constructor

Comment: You did not understand polymorphism. You cannot 'override' data. Read about methods overriding.

Comment: @ZDF code has been edited. It used to say `char symbol = 'C1';` which is not valid. (one char has the single char value 'C1'??)

Comment: I should make a contructor for it. Thank you for your help. I have a big knowlegde gaps so I don't see a point of making this subject logner.

Answer (score 2):

CRTP aka static inheritance can help here:

```
struct A{
    virtual char get_symbol() const = 0;
};

template<typename Derived>
struct C : public A{
    virtual char get_symbol() const override {
         return static_cast<Derived const&>(*this).symbol;
    }
};

struct C1 : public C<C1>{
    char symbol = '#';
};
```